# Null Pointer Exception in Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I'm having a rather annoying issue with a shopping servlet I'm designing. I keep getting a null pointer exception when I try setting up an order object like this:

```
           int ccn=customer.getCcn();
            OrderList.Order order=null;
    ResultSet set=helper.selectOrder(custId);
    try{
        while (set.next()){
            orderno=set.getInt(1);
            orderDate=set.getString(2);
            shipDate=set.getString(3);
            custId=set.getString(4);
            order=list.new Order(orderno,custId,ccn);
            list.addOrder(order);

        }
        set.close();}
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

But if I do this, the exception goes away... but my list is full of duplicates.

```
            int ccn=customer.getCcn();
    ResultSet set=helper.selectOrder(custId);
    try{
        while (set.next()){
            orderno=set.getInt(1);
            orderDate=set.getString(2);
            shipDate=set.getString(3);
            custId=set.getString(4);
        }
        set.close();}
                    OrderList.Order order=list.new Order(orderno,custId,ccn);
                    list.addOrder(order);
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you supply which line gives you the exception and a bit more context to the code, like where list is defined?

Comment: We cannot help you without a **stacktrace**.

Comment: @kenju please stop doing irrelevant edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an rough, uneducated (if one can say that) guess, so here goes.

If `list` is **definitely** not null, then the easiest way is to add the new order directly in the list like so:

```
while (set.next()){
    orderno=set.getInt(1);
    orderDate=set.getString(2);
    shipDate=set.getString(3);
    custId=set.getString(4);
    list.addOrder(list.new Order(orderno,custId,ccn));
}
```